# What happens on $\mid z \mid =1$ for $\sum_{1}^{\infty}sin(z^n)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

What happens on $\mid z \mid =1$ for $\sum_{1}^{\infty}sin(z^n)$? I know that inside the unit disk, the sum defines an analytic function. However, on the boundary I cannot find a way to make out of the series...Could anyone please help me?

Comment: It is quite obvious $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} \frac{1}{1-z^{2k+1}}$ isn't  analytic at any point of the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(z)$ is never $0$ on the unit circle, and the unit circle is compact so $\sin(z)$ is bounded away from $0$ there.  An infinite series can't converge unless its terms go to $0$.

Comment: Oh I missed such a simple fact.....

Comment: However, is there any analytic continuation of the series beyond the disc of convergence? Actually that was what I was curious about.

Comment: @Keith: $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\cdot\frac{1}{z^{2k+1}-1}$$ is convergent for any $|z|>1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But does that have an analytic continuation across the circle?